# Make users manually update app

Tags: ios, plist, auto-update

In iOS7 my application is automatically updated... Is there any way I can release an update of my app and make the plist or something so that the app will NOT be auto-updated by the device, but instead users will only get the update if the manually go to the AppStore and update it?

Comment: No, there is no way to do this.  Why do you want to?

Comment: One example would be if the app had an SQLite database that could only be upgraded destructively.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. You need to find a way to notify your users their app has been updated. For example, alert your users the first time their open the app that it has been updated.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm actually curious in making users manually update the app as opposed to having Apple's new "Auto-update" feature do it without them knowing. This is more of an iOS7 question :) That is a good tactic for gaining updates before the auto-update feature though!

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw It is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Clash of Clans app prompts an alert telling that there is a new update available. The caveat is that this is a online game so the user needs to have internet access to play it. If the user expects to use your application offline and you previously stored an information that the app needs an update and you don't allow the user use it can be frustrating.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm actually curious in making users manually update the app as opposed to having Apple's new "Auto-update" feature do it without them knowing. This is more of an iOS7 question :) That is a good tactic for gaining updates before the auto-update feature though! (P.s. Love Clash Of Clans!)